# Печать на принтер xls файлов из java под linux'ом

Tags: java, linux, xls

Не получается реализовать метод печати файлов екселя из java приложения, пробовал двумя способами:
1.

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
File temp = null;

if (d.isSupported(Desktop.Action.PRINT)) {
   for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
       temp = fileList.get(i);
       d.print(temp);
   }
}
```

2.

```
int n = printComboBox.getSelectedIndex();

SimpleDoc simpleDoc = null;
DocPrintJob job = null; 

for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
    simpleDoc = new SimpleDoc(new FileInputStream(fileList.get(i)), DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
    job = printServices[n].createPrintJob();
    job.print(simpleDoc, null);
}
```

в 1м случае не проходит проверку, если ее убрать то:

> The PRINT action is not supported on the current platform!

во 2м :

> java.io.IOException: error=1 running: '/usr/bin/lpr' '-PHewlett-Packard-HP-LaserJet-M1536dnf-MFP' '-J Java Printing' '-o media=Letter' '/tmp/javaprint6569831291945530199'
>           /usr/bin/lpr: Неподдерживаемый document-format "application/msword".

Comment: Для Python есть хороший пакет `openpyxl`, про Java не знаю.